# Alternative approach to derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Recall that the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $a$ is defined as the limit:

$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$, if the limit exists.

Can we alternatively formulate it as

$\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f(g(x))-f(h(x))}{g(x)-h(x)}$, where $\lim_{x\to b}g(x)=\lim_{x\to b}h(x)=a$?

Are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: NO...................................

Comment: would have worked if $lim_{g(x)\to b}\frac{f(g(x))-f(h(x))}{g(x)-h(x)} $ and $lim_{x\to g^-{1}(b)}h(x)=a$

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define the derivative as such.  For instance, let $a=b=0$ and

$$f(x)\equiv |x|, g(x)\equiv |x|, h(x)\equiv 0.$$ Then $f'(a)$ is not well- defined but

$$\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f(g(x))-f(h(x))}{g(x)-h(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{|x|-0}{|x|-0}=1.$$

---

Now under special circumstances, your limit may indeed be equal to $f'(a).$ For instance, for $f$ continuously differentiable at $a$ and $g,h$ continuously differentiable at $b$ with $g'(b)\neq h'(b)$ then L'Hopital's rule tells us

$$\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f(g(x))-f(h(x))}{g(x)-h(x)}=\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f'(g(x))g'(x)-f'
(h(x))h'(x)}{g'(x)-h'(x)}=f'(a).$$